# Is there any possibility to use the css classes of twitter bootstrap in shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, web-component, shadow-dom

Is there any possibility to use twitter bootstrap inside shadow dom? At this point, a major advantage turns out to be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert the Bootstrap CSS file inside the Shadow DOM with a `<link href="stylesheet">` element:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```js
customElements.define( 'c-e', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
        .innerHTML = `
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">Hello</button>
        `
  }
} )
```

```html
<c-e></c-e>
```

Comment: Do you also know how to get the javascript part of bootstrap working?

Comment: @Andi it's a bigger problem. I'm not a Bootstrap specialist so you should provide a example because maybe the answer depends on the use case.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake; the answer you gave was absolutely correct and universal.

Comment: @Andi No I don't think that controls that need JS won't work in Shadow DOM. A workaround  would be to put the controls in the Light DOM and instert then in the Shadow DOM via slots.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `::shadow` selector to style elements in the shadow DOM, I believe.

Comment: I don't want to apply own, but the bootstrap styles.